# Imbalance of variables in Mixing Newton's method and Linear solver for a Non-linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, nonlinear-equations, newton-method

**Problem**

Solving a non-linear system of equations.

The number of variables is the same as the number of equations.

When I fix a set of variables (say $\vec{y}$) and keep another set free (say $\vec{x}$), the system becomes an **under-determined**, dense, and linear system of the subset of variables 
$$A(\vec{y})\vec{x} = \vec{b}(\vec{y})\tag{1}\label{system1}$$

where $A(\vec{y})$ is a dense matrix, and $\vec{b}(\vec{y})$ is a dense vector). Let's call this sub-system $\eqref{system1}$ as *system 1*.

When I fix $\vec{x}$ and keep $\vec{y}$ free, the system becomes an **over-determined**, sparse, and non-linear system of the subset of variables 
$$F(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = 0\tag{2}\label{system2}$$

The Jacobian $J(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ is available in a closed form. Let's call this sub-system $\eqref{system2}$ as *system 2*.

About half of the equations in $\eqref{system2}$ are equality constraints that are linear in terms of $\vec{y}$. Each of the constraints is quite sparse and involves only about 5% of all variables.

Can I solve it with the following?

**Algorithm 1**

1. Initialize $\vec{x} = \vec{x}_0$, and $\vec{y} = \vec{y}_0$
2. Fix $\vec{y}_{n - 1}$, solve $A(\vec{y}_{n-1})\vec{x}_{n} = \vec{b}(\vec{y}_{n-1})$ for one of all the possible $\vec{x}_{n}$ because this system is *under-determined*.
3. Fix $\vec{x}_{n - 1}$. Perform one iteration of Newton's method for solving $F(\vec{x}_{n-1}, \vec{y}_{n}) = 0$ for $\vec{y}_{n}$.
4. If not converged, go to step 2.

**Algorithm 2**

If I replace step 2 in Algorithm 1 by a Newton's method iteration for solving *system 1* $\eqref{system1}$, then I guess the steps become a block Newton's method.

**Question**

But I don't know if these two algorithms can work because system 1 $\eqref{system1}$ is under-determined and system 2 $\eqref{system2}$ is over-determined.

Can this work?

**Related**

- [A. Yeckel, L. Lun, and J. J. Derby, "An approximate block Newton method for coupled iterations of nonlinear solvers: Theory and conjugate heat transfer applications," *J. Comp. Phys.*, vol. 228, no. 23, pp. 8566–8588, Dec. 2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2009.08.003)
- [B. Polyak and A. Tremba, "Solving underdetermined nonlinear equations
  by Newton-like method"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07810.pdf) 
  Solving over-determined non-linear equations with Newton's method and Moore-Penrose inverse is fine.
- [V. Meñkov. "Solving block linear system with low-rank off diagonal blocks is easily parallelizable"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/30ad/d70c4afaf2b17349ffe03524a78dae7d4e04.pdf)
  Block triangular form allows some blocks to be over-determined while other blocks to be under-determined. Newton's method is equivalent to solving the system linearized at current approximation of solution. The question is equivalent to if it is possible to solve a system of linear equations by alternatively performing iterations of Newton's method on two groups of variables.
- [Śmietański, M. J. "A generalized Jacobian based Newton method for semismooth block-triangular system of equations" *J. Comput. Appl. Math.*. 2007.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042706003190)
  Solving block triagular system by newton iteration on each block can work. "We prove locally superlinear convergence of parameterized version method that is well defined even when the generalized Jacobian is singular."

Comment: How do you choose which variables belong to set $\vec{x}$ and which to $\vec{y}$?

Comment: The system is linear in terms of the variables $\vec{x}$. The remaining variables are  $\vec{y}$.

Comment: I see. What I would do at a first glance, is add however many variables from Y to the X subset to make the number of equations match number of variables, and linearize the corresponding equations to get the first approximation. Then use the Newton's method on both subsets as intended. But that's just an idea, I'm not sure if it will work

Comment: Can't linearize (theoretically without numerical methods) around the solution because I don't have a good theoretical approximation of the solution. I think Newton's method is equivalent to linearization at the current approximation of the solution, using the Jacobian. Moving variables from Y to X has several disadvantages in terms of programming. It makes system 1 not linear and not dense anymore. That means higher memory usage and forced to use slower methods. Solving sparse system is much slower than solving a dense system. Speed is crucial as I have to speed up the program by 50 times.

Comment: @YuriyS Maybe. Suppose we linearize the whole thing around the current approximation of the solution. Then the question is equivalent to solving a linear system by block matrix method with the variables split unevenly. If that can work, then the scheme in the question can work.

Comment: Use automatic differentiation to linearize?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I already have the Jacobian in close form (I do it by hand, no need for automatic differentiation). Newton's method is equivalent to linearization, using the Jacobian. Also, linearize around what point? How would linearization prove/disprove that the algorithm would work?

Comment: It's similar to iterative least squares approximations in ML. It can be hard to prove that it will converge, but even so it's useful in practice. I suspect similarly for this: no one can prove/disprove that it will work, but with a decent initial condition you should be fine. It's worth a shot at least.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about the iterative least squares that you refer to? When I search online for iterative least squares, there are too many different things. For convergence, some algorithm needs positive definite matrix to work, and some depends on the eigenvalues of the Jacobian. I don't know how well would algorithm 1/2 work.

Comment: As your bounty is almost over, maybe you can think of what kind of answer you really want? Because I doubt anyone can answer "can this work" without first trying/doing some experiments with the method, using your data. At least that would be the most useful way to check the validity of the method. I'm sure there's some general theory available, but checking directly is usually my first choice

Comment: I thought it is "just" linear algebra. If no one can see obvious loopholes of this method (about convergence and stability), I guess I will just go ahead and program the whole thing. I might also post the question in sundial/other non-linear optimization/solver's forum. Or try theoretical computer science stack exchange.

Comment: Probably can work. This is equivalent to a block triangular approximation of the Jacobian. I am still not completely sure if the unbalance of variables would cause any problem.

Comment: Probably can work because this is equivalent to a block triangular approximation of the Jacobian. I got the answer from the SUNDIALS mail list: http://sundials.2283335.n4.nabble.com/Solving-a-non-linear-system-with-a-linear-sub-system-td4654414.html